# Trajectory of a particle in a force vector field

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, projectile-motion

Let's say I have a vector force field as <x, y>, I.e force depends on the position.

Now I have a body of mass m, initial position S = <p1, p2> and initial velocity u = <u1, u2>. How can I write an equation for the trajectory for this particle with respect to time?

Comment: Anything that changes the path of a particle from a line with constant velocity is called a force. This is formalized as changing the second derivative from zero, meaning $\ddot p = F(t,p,\dot p)/m$, $p=(x,y)$. So you get a rather general second order differential equation that you sometimes can solve symbolically. Most often the best you get is a function table of approximate values via a numerical method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Newton's equation of motion,
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \bar{r} = \frac{1}{m} \bar{F}(\bar{r})$$

If you have two dimensions, say $\bar{r} = x \cdot \hat{e_x} + y \cdot \hat{e_y}$, then you get two coupled differential equations,
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} x(t) - \frac{1}{m} F_x(x(t), y(t)) = 0$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} y(t) - \frac{1}{m} F_y(x(t), y(t)) = 0$$

Depending on the force function, you solve for these differential equations with the initial conditions.